# The Relevance of Bread and Wine

Tags: eucharist, body-of-christ, didache

It's very known that before eating and drinking (that will be quoted respectively), jewish people have the habit to say

> Barukh ata Adonai Eloheinu melekh ha’olam hamotzi lehem min ha’aretz.

which means *Blessed are You, Lord our God, Ruler of the universe, who brings forth bread from the earth.*

And also:

> Barukh ata Adonai Eloheinu melekh ha’olam borei p’ri hagafen.

Which means almost the same as above: *Blessed are You, Lord our God, Ruler of the universe, who creates the fruit of the vine.*

It's also known that in Christianism, Eucharist ✠ (Chapter IX of **Didache**) is one of the great mysteries and of faith. The question that intrigues me is, what is the prophecy that says that the bread is the body of Christ and the wine is his blood before the New Testment (Luke 22:19)?

> 19 And he took **bread**, gave thanks and broke it, and gave it to them,
> saying, “This is my **body** given for you; do this in remembrance of me.”
> (NIV)

And the blessing of wine:

> 20 In the same way, after the supper he took the **cup**, saying, “This
> cup is the new covenant in my **blood**, which is poured out for you.

Comment: Jesus instituted an ordinance (the partaking of bread an wine in remembrance). The ordinance was neither present, nor prophesied of, prior to its inauguration. Why do you think it would be prophesied before it was given ?

Comment: A lot of things in the Bible are prophesied before they happen. John 6:53ff. would be a passage to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Many debates have been waged over the proper elements to use in observing the Lord’s Supper. It was clearly a command under the Old Testament to use unleavened bread in the Passover meal (Exodus 12:15), so it is certain that this unleavened bread was what Jesus broke and said symbolized His body.

It is equally clear that the Jews used wine during the Passover meal, and this was what Jesus used to symbolize His blood. Both unleavened bread and wine have symbolism uniquely suiting them to the Lord’s Supper: In the Scriptures, leaven symbolized sin (Matthew 13:33), and when we partake of communion, we are admonished to “examine ourselves” so we will not partake of the body and blood of the Lord Jesus “unworthily” (1 Corinthians 11:27-29).

Although this *symbolism* is not to be ignored, it is entirely wrong to place more importance on the *elements* themselves than on what they represent. Jesus repeatedly rebuked the Pharisees for this same error in other areas (Matthew 23:19 and Matthew 23:26). Jesus made a point of saying that this Supper was for the purpose of ***remembering*** Him (Luke 22:19).

It all comes back to the origin of Passover. *Pesach*.

> **EXODUS 12:14** *This is a day you are to commemorate; for the generations to come you shall celebrate it as a festival to the Lord—a lasting ordinance*

The *bread* symbolises the ‘body’ of Messiah. That ‘body’ that was *substituted* in place of the firstborn. That He would take the death. And the blood symbolises the promise God made to protect them. That he would take what was due to them.

The ‘law of first mention’ helps here in understanding the symbol of the bread *being the body*, and the protection offered by the blood. Bread and wine are first ‘seen’ in Genesis…

> **GEN 14:18** *Then Melchizedek king of Salem brought out bread and wine.*

The symbology of ‘bread’ and ‘wine’ is found throughout the Bible, and although the meaning may have changed slightly, nevertheless, in each occasion where it is found that symbology is always clear. With the ‘focus’ being remembrance and substitution.